# How to access an array key with double quotes

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file using php,

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("upload/" . 
$newfilename,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);

foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
  $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}

foreach ($csv as $row) {
  echo $row["Due"];
}

var_dump($csv);
```

but when I view the dump of the array the Due array key has double quotes

```
array(20) { [0]=> array(10) { [""Due""]=> string(8) "30/06/17"
```

The csv file doesn't have 'Due' in quotes, I'm not sure where the extra quotes are coming from, all the rest of the keys are normal

Ive tried the following just to try getting it to work

```
echo $csv['Due'];
echo $csv['"Due"'];
echo $csv["\"Due\""];
echo $csv["Due"];
```

but none work

a dump of the keys looks like

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(8) ""Due"" [1]=> string(5) "Round" [2]=> string(4) "Jobs" [3]=> string(3) "New" [4]=> string(7) "Overdue" [5]=> string(8) "Due Jobs" [6]=> string(9) "Worksheet" [7]=> string(9) "Avg Price" [8]=> string(6) "Weekly" [9]=> string(7) "Monthly" }
```

and the top line of the CSV file looks like

```
"Due","Round","Jobs","New","Overdue","Due Jobs","Worksheet","Avg Price","Weekly","Monthly"
```

Comment: what's `var_dump($keys);` look like?

Comment: As a note, the `echo $csv["Due"];` line would not affect whats stored in `$csv`

Comment: Try again using `$csv[0]` instead of `$csv` you've got a multidimensional array. or test within your `foreach ($csv as $row)` loop using `$row`

Comment: @rtfm I've updated the question with $keys.

Comment: You provided everything but a sample of the actual data that causes the situation to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by opening the CSV file and re-doing the quotation marks "

I checked the ASCII values for the quotation marks I removed and replaced them with and they were exactly the same.

I resolved the issue in php by doing a string replace removing any quotation marks "

```
$keys[0] = str_replace('"', "", $keys[0]);
```

I am still unsure what was causing this, as when I dumped the $keys variable it didnt show the quotation marks.